# Flutter Flame Game Unit Test Not Working: How do I fix my test case below so that I can test tap events for flame components within my flame game?

Tags: flutter, flame

Here is the development test I am trying to run:

```
testWithGame<ExampleGame>("back button can be tapped", ExampleGame.new,
    (game) async {
  await game.ready();
  final Button component = game.backButton!;
  int backButtonPointerID = game.children.length - 3;
  game.onTapDown(
      backButtonPointerID,
      createTapDownEvent(game,
          globalPosition:
              Offset(component.position.x, component.position.y)));
  expect(component.tapped, true);
});
```

Any thoughts as to why this isn't registering a tap? It should evaluate to true but evaluates to false. When playing the game itself it registers as true, but the unit test doesn't...

Answer (score 0):

The button is most likely not added to the game yet, but will be added in the next tick (if you add it properly, it would help to have that code in the question too).

Try to run `game.update` after `game.ready`, or add `await` to the add call if you are doing it in the game's `onLoad` method.

Comment: I found the issue. It was that my custom component didn't have this line

@override
  bool containsPoint(Vector2 point) => true;

Comment: Like I said on Discord, that is the wrong way to solve it, when doing it like that it means you are not setting the size or hitboxes properly somewhere.